# what is flash domain memory?

Tags: flash

I am breaking my head since a couple of days to find answer the meaning and purpose of domain memory. Every where I found is the licensing/fees stuff but not the definition. Can some one help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote from the [first Google result on `flash domain memory`](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/premium-features-licensing-faq.html#u)

> **What are the domain memory APIs?**
>   In 2009, Adobe released a preview
>   of the project codenamed "Alchemy," a prototype of a C/C++
>   cross-compiler that targets Flash Player. As part of the research
>   project, we introduced a new domain memory API to support the
>   compiler. In September 2011, we announced plans to invest in the
>   technology and release it as part of a paid production offering for
>   commercial development. We are now renaming project “Alchemy,” the
>   Flash Runtime  C++ Compiler (flascc).

Answer (score 0):

From the [link](http://www.informationweek.com/development/mobility/adobe-upgrades-flash-player-adds-gaming/232700429)

> Adobe's updated software provides developers with the option of using
>   hardware-accelerated graphics and/or sandboxed native C/C++ code
>   (Adobe calls this "domain memory") in their Flash-based games.

**EDIT**::
Another [link](http://ncannasse.fr/blog/virtual_memory_api), AFAIK, these are the APIs Flash made available to developers.